# Как добавить кнопку для включения/выключения маркера на карте leaflet?

Tags: javascript, angular

Как добавить кнопку для включения/выключения маркера на карте leaflet?

Answer (score 1):

Маркеры в `leaflet` это обычные элементы, спозиционированные через `css`, спрятать их можно тем же `css`, только следует учесть что их там может быть два, маркер и тень

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<style>
  div#map {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  button{
    position:absolute;
    left:60px;
    top:20px;
  }
  .hidden {
    display:none!important;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>

<script>
  var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

  var osmLayer = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
      maxZoom: 18
  });

  var baseMaps = {"OpenStreetMap": osmLayer};

  var map = new L.Map('map', {
      center: new L.LatLng(60, 30.3),
      zoom: 7,
      layers: [osmLayer]
  });

  var marker = L.marker([60, 30.3]).addTo(map);

  function toggle() {
    marker._icon.classList.toggle('hidden')
    marker._shadow.classList.toggle('hidden')
  }
</script>
```